# Массив таблицы умножения

Tags: javascript

Всем привет
Нужна помощь.
Создал я два массива, чтобы выводились они как таблица умножения.
Как мне обратиться, к примеру ко второму эл. в строке и второму эл. в столбце, и получить пересечение элементов - то есть 4. если 5 и 5 - то 25.

```js
let arr = "";
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    arr += j * i + " ";
    if (j >= 9) {
      arr += ' \n';
    }
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Ну или скорей всего, я не так делаю.

Comment: `arr[j][i] = j * i;` ?

Comment: "Создал я два массива" - где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Как мне обратиться, к примеру ко второму эл. в строке и второму эл. в столбце, и получить пересечение элементов - то есть 4*

Если хранить таблицу умножния в виде строки, как у Вас, нам будет очень сложно и неефективно достать число из неё. Другое дело хранить все числа в двумерном массиве, в примерном формате:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
  [0, 2, 4, 6]
  [0, 3, 6, 9]
]
```

Зачем нам хранить числа, которые начинаются с нуля? Все просто, чтобы потом было удобнее брать их произведение, пример: `arr[5][5]` будет `25`.

```js
// Создаем
let arr = Array(10);
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = [...Array(10)].map((_, j) => i * j);
}

console.log(arr)

// Делаем таблицу текстом
let s = '';
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  s += arr[i].slice(1).join(' ') + '\n';
}

console.log(s);         // Вся таблица
console.log(arr[5][5]); // 25
```